# How to improve the algorithm sum?

Tags: java

Consider the source code:

```
public class subSetSumR {
    // Solving Subset sum using recursion
    // Programmed by Fuentes, Feb. 9, 2009
    // Subset sum consists of finding a subset of mySet whose elements add up to goal
    // It is a well-known NP-complete problem

    public static boolean subSetSumRecur (int[] mySet, int n, int goal) {
        if (goal == 0) return true;

        if ((goal < 0) | (n >= mySet.length)) return false;

        if (subSetSumRecur(mySet, n + 1, goal - mySet[n])) {
             System.out.print(mySet[n] + " ");
             return true;
        }

        if (subSetSumRecur(mySet, n + 1, goal)) return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Important fact: The number of the input is greater than 1 How do I use this fact to speed up the above solution?

Comment: Might be a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If the variable `goal` is your input, then there are a couple of statements that can be trivially removed.

Comment: @Jongware, could you write more?

Comment: Uh, lots. If you are sure `goal` is greater than 1 then there is no need for the tests if it is 0 or less. Hence, "trivially".

Comment: @Jongware Those tests are the base cases of the recursion and essential for the algorithm to work! `goal` is decremented in each recursive call, so it it is zero, you hit the goal, and if it's smaller you overshot.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to avoid repeated calculations.
2. You can use [dp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to do things better. (Start with an empty hash set and incrementally grow the set by adding number 1 by 1 from your array)

```
    set = emptyset;
    for(num : array_of_number)
    {
      newset = emptyset;
      for(item : set)
      {
        if(num + item == goal) return ""we found it";
        newset.insert(num + item);
      }
      set.insert(newset);
    }
    return "Not possible";
```

Memoization

```
set<tuple<int, int>> memo; // Make sure to clear before calling your function
public static boolean subSetSumRecur (int[] mySet, int n, int goal) {
  if( set.contains( tuple(n, goal) ) return false;
  set.insert( tuple(n, goal) );
  ...
  ... /* Your code goes here */
  ...
}
```

In java there should be something similar to set (I think hashset) and tuple (In C++ std::pair is the best choice. If there is nothing similar in java you can make a small class containining 2 ints that is insertable into a hashset).

Comment: Memoization can give speed up your code. Before calling subSetSumRecur  for the first time, initialize memo. Now if memo[goal][n] is unitialized, after getting the answer, save it into memo[goal][n] else return readily available answer.